# Entity Component System (ECS): Entity-Exclusive Component Data Being Shared Among All Entities With That Component

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, sdl, entity-component-system

I will try to keep this brief

### **THE CONTEXT**

My basic C++ (SDL & OpenGL) 2D game engine has an ECS. I have a system called **TextSystem**, which requires 3 components. *TransformComponent*, *RenderComponent*, & *TextComponent*.

This is a code snippet of the signatures being set for the systems.

```
ECSHandler::Instance()->Init();

//Register components.
ECSHandler::Instance()->RegisterComponent<TransformComponent>();
ECSHandler::Instance()->RegisterComponent<RenderComponent>();
ECSHandler::Instance()->RegisterComponent<TextComponent>();

//movement signature here

renderSignature.set(ECSHandler::Instance()->GetComponentType<TransformComponent>());
renderSignature.set(ECSHandler::Instance()->GetComponentType<RenderComponent>());

textSignature.set(ECSHandler::Instance()->GetComponentType<TransformComponent>());
textSignature.set(ECSHandler::Instance()->GetComponentType<RenderComponent>());
textSignature.set(ECSHandler::Instance()->GetComponentType<TextComponent>());

//Register systems.
//mpMovementSystem = ECSHandler::Instance()->RegisterSystem<MovementSystem>();
mpRenderSystem = ECSHandler::Instance()->RegisterSystem<RenderSystem>();
mpTextSystem = ECSHandler::Instance()->RegisterSystem<TextSystem>();
//ECSHandler::Instance()->SetSystemSignature<MovementSystem>(signature);
ECSHandler::Instance()->SetSystemSignature<RenderSystem>(renderSignature);
ECSHandler::Instance()->SetSystemSignature<TextSystem>(textSignature);

//mpSystems.insert({ typeid(MovementSystem).name(), mpMovementSystem });
mpSystems.insert({ typeid(RenderSystem).name(), mpRenderSystem });
mpSystems.insert({ typeid(TextSystem).name(), mpTextSystem });
```

All the **TextSystem** does is, sets the "texture" variable in the *RenderComponent* to a texture made from text/font. This is done using a function called LoadTextureFromFont.

Another system which handles rendering, the **RenderingSystem**, automatically has the entity added if it is already registered to a **TextSystem** as the **RenderingSystem** has all the components that a **TextSystem** needs, the *transform* and *render* component.

So, the **TextSystem** changes the texture of an entity to update it according to the text input (the "output" variable in the *TextComponent*) and the **RenderSystem** renders that entity.

```cpp
    void TextSystem::Update()
    {
        for (auto const& entity : mEntities)
        {
            auto& render = ECSHandler::Instance()->GetComponent<RenderComponent>(entity);
            auto& text = ECSHandler::Instance()->GetComponent<TextComponent>(entity);

            render.texture = ResourceManager::LoadTextureFromFont(text.output, true, text.font);
        }
    }
```

```cpp
    void RenderSystem::Draw()
    {
        for (auto const& entity : mEntities)
        {
        auto& transform = ECSHandler::Instance()->GetComponent<TransformComponent>(entity);
        auto& render = ECSHandler::Instance()->GetComponent<RenderComponent>(entity);

        ...

        glBindVertexArray(mQuadVAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
}
```

**TextSystem**'s Update is called before **RenderingSystem**'s Draw.

### **THE ISSUE**

When re-assigning the texture variable in the *render* component for an entity registered in **TextSystem**, the latest texture that is applied (via LoadTextureFromFont) is applied to ALL entities that have a *TextComponent*. Essentially, the last *TextComponent* becomes the *TextComponent* for all entities that have said component. The size of the texture is made according to the original text's size, so texts that are long but have been replaced by the newest text will look dis-proportionate.

```
ResourceManager::AddText("testText", "Message", glm::vec2(200.f, 200.f), ResourceManager::GetFont("CircularMedium"));
ResourceManager::AddText("testText2", "This is a message.", glm::vec2(300.f, 200.f), ResourceManager::GetFont("CircularMedium"));
```

[image]

This is not happening with any other component, strictly this component (which holds only a string and font object) is seemingly not entity-exclusive.

I've tried all I could to fix this (10-12 hours...) and Googling did not yield desired results.

If anything at all is needed (more code snippets and/or context) please let me know! I am not sure if this question suits Stack Overflow or Game Development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Texture" variable being returned from GetTextureFromFont was a global variable.